# mySql INSERT query doesn't return nothing, even after res.json() in node

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I'm recently started with node and I found myself in the middle of a problem.

I'm trying to Insert a product in my table, but for the id of the product i did not set as auto-increment, so for me to save the id i'm doing a "SELECT MAX"; something like:

```
 router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const { product_description, product_sale_price, product_brand }
    conn.query('SELECT MAX(id_product) as id_product FROM products', (error, results) => {
       if (error) res.json(error);

       let id_max = results[0].id_product
       id_max = id_max === null ? 1 : id_max + 1;

       conn.query(
          `INSERT INTO produtos (id_product, product_description, product_sale_price, id_brand) VALUES ('${id_max}', '${product_description}', '${product_sale_price}', '${product_brand}')`,
          (error, results) => {
           if (error) res.json(error);

          res.json({ message: "Everything ok!" })
      })`
   })
})
```

But nothing is returned, recording is normally done in the database but nothing returns in the `res.json({ message: "Everything ok!" })`;

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are working with a single table. So I would try fixing the typo in the `INSERT` statement.

```js
`INSERT INTO products (id_product, product_description, product_sale_price, id_brand) VALUES ('${id_max}', '${product_description}', '${product_sale_price}', '${product_brand}')`,
```

Comment: The original code has `INSERT INTO produtos` (typo in table name) vs `INSERT INTO products`

Comment: Oh! But that's not it, this is just a typo when I was writing the answer, everythig has the same name.